# Android - a distance between real drawing and finger movement

Tags: android, user-interface, view, draw, touch-event

I am very new in Android Development, and I have a question here since I haven't found any answer on Stackoverflow.

I have written a simple code to let a user draw a bounding box with one finger on the screen(from the left upper corner to the right bottom corner).

The class DrawView looks like this:

```
public class DrawView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public Point startPoint = new Point();
public Point endPoint = new Point();

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    canvas.drawRect(startPoint.x,startPoint.y,endPoint.x,endPoint.y,paint);
}}
```

and the mainActivity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DrawView drawView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    drawView.startPoint.set(0,0);
    drawView.endPoint.set(0,0);
    setContentView(drawView);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int eventAction = event.getAction();

    // you may need the x/y location
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    // put your code in here to handle the event
    switch (eventAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawView.startPoint.set(x,y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawView.endPoint.set(x,y);
            drawView.invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawView.endPoint.set(x,y);
            drawView.invalidate();
            break;
    }

    // tell the View that we handled the event
    return true;
}}
```

And the result is a significant distance between my finger point and the real drawing point on the screen that looks like this:

[on screen result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7lS1.png)

The blue line is my finger and the red bounding box is the real drawing on the screen. Does anyone know the reason for this? Thanks very much!

Comment: It's because the `View`'s coordinates are different than the `Activity`'s. Handle the touch events in the `View` itself. That is, move the `onTouchEvent()` method to your `DrawView`.

Answer (score 0):

Activity & child View don't have the same coordinates origin. I did some corrections :

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener{

        DrawView drawView;         

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            drawView = new DrawView(this);
            drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            drawView.startPoint.set(0, 0);
            drawView.endPoint.set(0, 0);
            setContentView(drawView);
            drawView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        }



        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            int eventAction = motionEvent.getAction();


            // you may need the x/y location
            int x = (int) motionEvent.getX();
            int y = (int) motionEvent.getY();

            // put your code in here to handle the event
            switch (eventAction) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    drawView.startPoint.set(x, y);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    drawView.endPoint.set(x, y);
                    drawView.invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    drawView.endPoint.set(x, y);
                    drawView.invalidate();
                    break;
            }

            // tell the View that we handled the event
            return true;
        }
    }
```